# Как определить, что андроидовский будильник установлен?

Tags: java, android

Как определить, что будильник установлен в дефолтном приложении на android?
Для api начиная с 21 есть метод

```
AlarmManager.getNextAlarmClock
```

А каким образом можно определить для более ранних версий андроида?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот такой код похоже работает

```
boolean isAlarmSet() {

        Context context = // получить контекст
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo alarmInfo = alarmManager.getNextAlarmClock();
            return (alarmInfo != null) && alarmInfo.getTriggerTime() >= System.currentTimeMillis();
        }

        String nextAlarm = Settings.System.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.NEXT_ALARM_FORMATTED);
        return nextAlarm != null && nextAlarm.length() > 0;
}
```